# Hive beeline failed, while configure Azure blob storage for hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-storage, kerberos

We have created a hadoop kerberos cluster with azure storage blob by following the below link. 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/index.html

Facing issue while connecting beeline shell of hive thirft server but same configuration for azure blob storage is working fine with normal cluster.

please find the issue details:

```
ERROR org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport$SaslParticipant.isComplete(TSaslTransport.java:547)
                at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:276)
                at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
                at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:761)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory$1.run(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:758)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
                at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1636)
                at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingTransportFactory.getTransport(HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:758)
                at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:269)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Can anyone help us to configure hive server2 with Azure blob storage instead of HDFS in kerberos hadoop cluster?

Thanks,
Selva